# Use V-Lookup to the cell number

Tags: vba, excel

So I have been given the task of comparing to worksheets in excel and if there is a match replacing the data from one cell with another, for example, I have 2 columns in 2 excel sheets, ID and name, I want to compare the IDs in sheet 1 with the IDs in sheet two and if it finds a match update the name linked with that ID.

Sheet 1

```
ID     Name
1      Thomas
2      Jerry
```

Sheet 2

```
ID    Name
3     Spike
1     Tom
```

So in the example above, I need the code to see that ID 1 is in both sheets and change the name in sheet 1 to match sheet 2, so that it looks like this:

```
ID    Name
1     Tom
2     Jerry
```

I'm trying to use the Vlookup, which has allowed me to find out if it is existing or not, but then I don't know how to change the cell to match the existing one, here is my code so far:

```
Range("C2").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = _
    "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP([@[ID]], 'Sheet2'!A:B,1,FALSE)), ""New"", ""Existing"")"

Do While Len(Range("A" & r).Formula) > 0

If (Range("C" & r).Value = "Existing") Then
   Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & r & ":B" & r).Copy _
   Destination:=Sheets("sheet1").Range("A" & r & ":B" & r)
Else
End If
```

I need to be able to get the cell number from the Vlookup so that I can use it in the if statement to pull in the correct data. There may be a simpler way to do this, if so I am open to changing everything.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a need of VBA for this task. As the names in "Sheet1" has to be updated by looking into the data in "Sheet2". Following formula can be used to find the updated names (by looking into data from the "Sheet2").

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A2:B3,2,FALSE),B2)
```

IFERROR is used so as to retain the names which were not found in "Sheet2" data. Have a look at following screenshot for the example.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is on a third sheet create 3 headings in row A: ID, Name and Source. Copy your data from sheet 1 into the first two columns and fill the third column with the text sheet 1. Do the same for sheet 2 but paste it below your sheet 1 data. You should end up with something like this:

```
ID  Name   Source
1   Thomas Sheet 1
2   Jerry  Sheet 1
3   Spike  Sheet 2
1   Tom    Sheet 2
```

Then just create a pivot table from this data with source as the column, name as the row and a count of name for the data. It should look something like this:

```
Name    Sheet 1  Sheet 2  Total
Thomas  1        0        1
Jerry   1        0        1
Spike   0        1        1
Tom     0        1        1
```

You can then sort on the Total column to find the duplicates which will have a total of two.

One other advantage of using this method is that it is quite easy to expand it to compare three or more lists.